# What exactly is a "PCI Express card slot (physical link width x16; negotiable link width x4, x1)"?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

From the manual of the Lenovo M93p (http://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1029184064.pdf):

[image]

The motherboard has 3 PCI Express slots:

- a "PCI Express x16 graphics card slot"
- a "PCI Express x1 card slot"
- and a "PCI Express card slot (physical link width x16; negotiable
  link width x4, x1)"

My question is, what is the difference if any between the first and the third slot?

Why does it have to specify "negotiable link width x4, x1" for the third slot if it is happening for the first slot anyway (if I understand it correctly) since you can just plug x1 and x4 cards into an x16 slot?

Will there be any problem using an x16 graphic card in the third slot?

Comment: I do not know precisely or exactly. I have an M90p here, and took the cover off. The long slot for the graphics card is vacant - I have Intel Graphics (located on the motherboard). One of the PCI-e slots (the first one after the long slot has an Intel Wireless adapter card in it so I can use my HUAWEI Internet Stick if no internet. The remaining slot is for another card (like the wireless card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first slot (27) is a regular PCIe slot with 16 lanes.

The third slot (25) is physically an x16 slot, but only 4 lanes are connected. Hence “negotiable link width x4, x1”.

Why build it like this? An x4 slot cannot physically fit an x16 card. There’s two (non-destructive) methods to allow you to plug one in anyway: A slot with the “backside” missing or just using an x16 slot. The latter also guarantees that there will be no conflicts with other components/heat sinks.